# Finding Shift-Invariant "Interesting" Elements In Words

Tags: optimization, word-combinatorics

I want to find "interesting" elements in a sequence of symbols that are independent of their absolute position in that sequence.

Formally, I have a window size $s \in \mathbb{N}$ and a finite alphabet $\Sigma$.
I'm looking for a function $f: \Sigma^s \to \{0, \; ..., \; s\}$ that points to the first interesting position of the input word that stays interesting even if the first character is removed and an arbitrary character is appended to the end.
This means:

$\forall w \in \Sigma^s, c \in \Sigma: f(w_0...w_{s-1}) > 0 \Rightarrow f(w_1...w_{s-1}c) = f(w_0...w_{s-1}) - 1$

Of course a trivial $f$ would always return $0$.
However, I'm most interested in a function $f$ that maximizes the average result, so that interesting positions are as far away from each other as possible.

Thus my question is: What is the $f$ that maximizes $\Sigma^{w \in \Sigma^s} f(w)$ (= the score of $f$)?

One idea would be to sort the alphabet and return the first index $i \leq s/2$ of the smallest symbol in $w_0...w_{i+i}$.
That way, after every shift of $w$, the index is decreased by $1$ until it reaches $0$.
What is an `f` with higher score?

Ideally, this function $f$ should also be fast to compute and not depend on brute forcing all possible $f$ first (there are only finitely many!).

One observation is that if $w = v^iv_0...v_j$ for some $i, j \in \mathbb{N}$ and $v \in \Sigma^*$, $j < |v|$, then $f(w) < s/i$. In particular $f(c...c) = 0$ for $c \in \Sigma$.

Comment: Assuming characters are i.i.d., I suspect the best solution is just to return the position of the leftmost occurrence of some fixed substring of length $O(\log_{|\Sigma|}s)$ (or 0 upon absence). If you have character frequencies (or are prepared to assume uniformity), you can choose the length to optimally trade off the probability of absence against the higher scores from "rarity". This is a simple calculation for uniformity; for given frequencies, brute-forcing all target strings would only be linear in $s$ (faster, in fact, since you would only need to check each character *multiset*).

Comment: A common generalization of "sort the alphabet and return the first index" and "find the leftmost occurrence of a pattern" is specifying a sequence of patterns $P_1, P_2, ... \in \Sigma^\ast$ that is an antichain then $f(S)$ returning the leftmost occurrence of the first pattern found in $S$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! @pcpthm what is the antichain condition needed for? And on what order?

Comment: I'm referring to the partial order of substring relation. If there is no restriction on $P$, the shift invariance of $f$ can be violated. Consider $P_1 = \text{bcd}, P_2 = \text{c}$, then $f(\text{abc}) = 2$ but $f(\text{bcd}) = 0$. The antichain condition is not a necessary, just a simple enough sufficient condition.

Answer (score 2):

Using an answer to write down a nice insight, inspired by the comments:

**Definition**. A function $f: \Sigma^s \to \{0, ..., s-1\}$ is called *shift-invariant* if $\forall w \in \Sigma^s, c \in \Sigma: f(w_0...w_{s-1}) > 0 \Rightarrow f(w_1...w_{s-1}c) = f(w_0...w_{s-1}) - 1$.

**Definition**. For a finite set of patterns $P \subseteq \Sigma^*$, define $f_P: \Sigma^s \to \{0, ..., s-1\} $ to be the function that returns the smallest position of where some $p \in P$ occurs in the input word, or $0$ if no pattern matches.

**Theorem**. Let $f: \Sigma^s \to \{0, ..., s-1\}$ be a shift-invariant function. Then there exists a finite set $P \subseteq \Sigma^*$ so that $f = f_P$.

*Proof*:

Set $P_f := P := \{ p \in \Sigma^* \; | \; \exists v \in \Sigma^*: |vp| = s \land f(vp) = |v| \}$.

Let $w \in \Sigma^s$ be an arbitray input word.

Set $vp := w$ with $|v| = f(w)$. Then $p \in P$ by definition of $P$.

Because (with $p$) at least some pattern in $P$ matches $w = vp$ at or before position $|v|$, by definition of $f_P$, there exists $p' \in P$ and $x, y \in \Sigma^*$ with $xp'y = w$, $|x| = f_P(w)$ and $|x| \leq |v|$.

Because $p' \in P$, there exists $v'$ so that $f(v'p') = |v'|$. Shift-invariance of $f$ now implies $f(p'u) = 0$ for any $u \in \Sigma^{|v'|}$.
Thus, $|v| = f(xp'y) \leq |x|$ (otherwise, shifting $|x|$ times doesn't reach $0$).
Finally we have $f(w) = |v| = |x| = f_P(w)$, which finishes the proof.

---

**Note**. If no element of $P$ is a substring of another, then $f_P$ is shift-invariant.

**Conjecture**. For a shift-invariant function $f$ it is $f = f_{P_f} = f_{P^{\mathrm{min}}_f}$ , with $P^{\mathrm{min}}_f$ being all minimal elements (regarding substrings) of $P_f$.

**Open Question**. What is $P$ such that $f_P$ is shift-invariant and $\Sigma_{w \in \Sigma^s} f_P(w)$ is maximal?